# Monitoring Play 2.0 apps

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

What is the recommended approach to monitoring Play 2.0 apps running in production?
Are log files the only way to get any visibility into the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logs are the main tool for monitoring. If you go "Pro" with Typesafe, you can get access to the [console](http://typesafe.com/products/console), which helps with monitoring.

There is also [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/product/real-user-monitoring), which provides a Heroku addon (if you use that platform).